# Feasability of Curve Hair With 2 point Cable-Like Attachments For UE5 Groom Sim of Chained Hair Sections As Stylized Hair Skyrockets Number of Bones

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, hair, unreal-engine

*ps: sorry for the massive text wall and possibly unhelpful images.*

**The title might a bit confusing so I'll elaborate on it:**

A bunch of models I'm working on **require cable-like 2 point attachments** for sections of the hair that need to work with simulation. I'm not asking for a way to make it work with UE5's groom sim but methods that could achieve this result in Blender for me to take care of the UE5 side after, that without a clear approach experimenting in UE5 becomes impossible if the hair connection method it self is experimental.

My attempts ***[see images]*** at it have been partially successful but I can't find a way to proceed without band-aid methods that cause a complete reset of progress on the side of UE5.

**Main Note:**

**The model is not a game model but a virtual production model for cinematics** in UE5's path tracer and I am working alone on it with no time or pipeline restrictions. Optimization is not an issue and I already know what to keep in mind as **I only have to tailor it to my machine**.
**Geometry nodes are not a problem as I'm using a plugin to export them to UE5**.

**Main Issues and Additional Notes:**

- the fundamental issue with using another mesh as
  attachment point is real curves will be affected by the set position
  node and the **[duplicate curves]** node makes a method to point the
  curve handles to be perpendicular to the circles something that is
  out of my knowledge.
- attach hair curves to surface doesn't work with hair tips and I couldn't find a way to pass an external uv map to it, deform to surface won't work either.
- the [root to first attachment] section is simulated with bones to allow the connection to move together with the second hair section.
- I attempted to make this with stylized hair, but it makes the number of bones sky rocket being that the hairs are made 1.50 meters patches and there are already 200+ for the body. Considering other actors bones and the bones for the character mechanical armor it would become a performance nightmare when animating.

  *(plus two solid pieces of geometry in front of the eyes just make the design look stupid tbf)*

*Side note: the number of bones for the body is that high so that I can have all the necessary bones to re-target animation from the human body to others instead of reanimating other skeletons for all the shape-shift sub models so that it only requires scale changes when directly animating scenes with sub model swaps.*

How Far I Managed to Get:
[image: How Far I Manage To Get]

What I'm Trying To Achieve:
[image: What I'm Trying To Achieve]

Full Hair Style For Reference:
[image: Full Hair Style For Reference]

Comment: Why do you capitalize every word? It makes it harder to read.

Comment: Have to agree with Markus. A quite long text written in an uncomfortable way for reading...